# ESP8266 (Wemos D1 Mini) gives wierd output after micropython installation

Tags: esp8266, micropython, thonny

I am currently working with a couple of ESP8266's using micropython and the Thonny IDE. Whenever the ESP boots up it gives some wierd unlegible output (see picture).

[image: Picture of the weird console output]

I have already tried another ESP of the same model, a different version of micropython, a different IDE (pyCharm) and a diffrenet USB-slot.

It is not a huge issue, as the code still runs, however it makes debugging harder and I would also like to know what causes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you're seeing is normal bootloader output from the ESP8266, which   is output at the unfortunate speed of 74880bps. Change your terminal speed to 74880bps and it should be legible (of course MicroPython's output won't be). It's harmless but if for any reason the ESP8266 crashed, it should have some information about the the cause of the crash.